# (Safely) change default install location?

Tags: windows-10

I want to change the default install location for all apps from:

```
C:\Program Files
```

To:

```
D:\Program Files
```

I found a [couple of articles](https://techcult.com/how-to-change-the-default-installation-directory-in-windows-10/#:%7E:text=How%20to%20change%20the%20default%20Installation%20Directory%20in,click%20on%20the%20ProgramFilesDir%20key.%20More%20items...%20) that say to edit the registry here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
```

They say to edit both:

- ProgramFilesDir
- ProgramFilesDir (x86)

However, when I do this, I now have a serious problem. When I try to OPEN an EXISTING app that was installed on the C drive, it tries to find it on the D drive, and of course it can't.

Is there a way to change ONLY the default install location? Or do I have to try and remember every time I install something to change it?

Comment: Why can't you simply move the files from the original location (other than WindowsApps) since that is performed within Store/Settings

Comment: @Ramhound, this only works for certain apps.

Comment: You can change the location, but lots of people who do this have long term problems with their computer - I always recommend against doing this.

Comment: Are we talking about desktop Win32 applications or UWP applications?  UWP applications should be uninstalled/installed to the new location.  You should be able to just move the installation folder for Win32 applications yourself.